# error C2065: 'lO' : undeclared identifier for declaring a vector value?

Tags: c++, vector

I dont know what I'm missing here.

I should be able to just state a vector and put values in it, right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Creating a lO element vector to hold scores.\n";
    vector<int> scores(lO, O); //initialize all l0 elements to O
    cout << "Vector size is :" << scores.size() << endl;
    cout << "Vector capacity is:" << scores.capacity() << endl;
    cout << "Adding a score.\n";
    scores.push_back(O); //memory is reallocated to accommodate growth
    cout << "Vector size is :" << scores.size() << endl;
    cout << "Vector capacity is:" << scores.capacity() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'lO' : undeclared identifier    
c:\users\ck\documents\visual Studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\vectortest.cpp  17  1   Project1
Error   2   error C2065: 'O' : undeclared identifier     
c:\users\ck\documents\visual Studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\vectortest.cpp  17  1   Project1
Error   3   error C2065: 'O' : undeclared identifier     
c:\users\ck\documents\visual Studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\vectortest.cpp  21  1   Project1
```

Comment: use a font that clearly differentiates `1`, `I`, `l` and `0`, `O` and you'll see the difference immediately. A good programming font always has those features

Comment: @phuclv I think you should post that as the better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the letters l (ell) and o (oh) instead of the numbers 1 and 0. You need to use numbers for immediate values.

Comment: There's a story there that's more interesting than this question.